# Add Oxford Comma to Natbib Intext Citation

Tags: natbib, punctuation

Using the natbib package, in Lyx, I would like to have intext (aka inline) citations in the format of

> (Angrist, Lang, and Oreopoulos 2009)

Default appears to be

> (Angrist, Lang and Oreopoulos, 2009)

and by adding to my preamble:
    \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}

I can achieve:

> (Angrist, Lang and Oreopoulos 2009)

but I am at a loss of how to get the oxford comma that I am looking for.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? It's the bibliography style that determines whether or not an Oxford comma is used. `natbib` only controls whether or not there's a comma between the author block and the year in the citation call-out, but *not* the presence of commas *within* the author block.

Answer (score 2):

Which `\bibliographystyle` are you using?  It works fine with `unsrtnat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}
\begin{document}
\citep*{epr}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{apssamp}
\end{document}
```

[image]